# Cron job doesn't work Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I have a problem with my cron job.

This is my script for creating mongodb backup:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Running scheduleSpider.sh at \`date\`" >> /tmp/scheduleSpider.sh.log
DIR=`date +\%m\%d\%y`
DEST=/dbbackups/$DIR
mkdir $DEST
mongodump -h localhost:27017 -d xxx -u xxx -p xxxx -o $DEST
```

This is crontab -u root -e table content:

```
* * * * * /aamycrons/dbbackup.sh
```

If I run in terminal:

```
 sh /aamycrons/dbbackup.sh
```

This works great its make my DB backup but cron doesn't do that, what em I doing wrong?

Comment: If you need to run `sh /aamycrons/dbbackup.sh` as opposed to `/aamycrons/dbbackup.sh` then you didn't make the script executable. Change permissions like with `chmod 755`

Comment: Hi @NeilLunn yes I did on script chmod +x,  but now i just changed my crontab command to ' * * * * * /bin/sh /aamycrons/dbbackup.sh'    adding /bin/sh  and it works!     thank you.

Comment: @NeilLunn: `chmod +x` is a bit simpler than `chmod 755`, and it respects your current umask. zire: if you do `chmod +x /aamycrons/dbbackup.sh`, then you shouldn't need the `/bin/sh` in your crontab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in my case was to add /bin/sh in crontab.
So final crontab -u root -e table content was:

```
* * * * * /bin/sh /aamycrons/dbbackup.sh
```

And it's working now!

Comment: I think you mean `crontab`, not "crontable".